# Angular Bootstrap Modal Slow ng-repeat in Google Chrome

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm using the $modal in [Angular Bootstrap UI](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) and have run into a performance issue in Google Chrome only.  I have an ng-repeat directive inside of my modal instance, and am binding it to 300 rows, and it's pegging my processor and locking up the browser for seconds.  This only happens in Google Chrome.  I tried it in Firefox and the same code works fine.  [Here's a plunker that illustrates the problem](http://plnkr.co/edit/qHyQElJ5D5rN4jEmFDit?p=preview) - if you open this in Chrome I suspect that you'll see the issue as well.

Am I doing something wrong here?  Why is this so taxing on the CPU when executed in Chrome as opposed to Firefox?  Using the same HTML and JavaScript WITHOUT the Bootstrap modal [works just fine](http://plnkr.co/edit/lbiDVRkCbsANUq4kvRKA?p=preview) in Chrome, so it must be something related to Bootstrap?

Comment: I tested your plunker in my Chrome browser and it worked fine, no delay at all. version: 35.0.1916.114 m

Comment: @m.e.conroy - Thanks for testing!  I'm running the same version of Chrome, so that's weird!

Comment: I'm using a pretty low powered laptop today and the same version of Chrome and am not seeing any problem on your Plunker, are other sites slow also?

Comment: @Andy only thing I can think of is that you have your machine taxed in other ways or maybe too many tabs open in Chrome?  At least you know it works as expected, just need to find out why it doesn't on your machine.

Comment: OK thanks for the help guys!  Maybe it's time for me to buy a new computer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like other comment I have no problem on my laptop in Chrome (win 64, Chrome 31)

But you have 900+ watchers on the modal scope (see : http://plnkr.co/edit/LIOAzVI4hACROqXlhICq?p=preview)

You should maybe take a look at [bindonce module](https://github.com/pasvaz/bindonce) to speed things up on low CPU devices

Comment: Thanks for the `bindonce` link, first time i've seen this and already loving it.