# Opening jpeg in Bootstrap Modal using Chrome slows down application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome

This does not happen in IE, but in Chrome, if I open a jpeg, then close modal, opening the same jpeg in the modal causes the response time of opening the modal and displaying the jpeg to slow each time it is called.  No problem shows in the Dev Tools.

Here is the modal code:

```
<div class="container" ng-cloak>
        <div id="imageViewer" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" data-focus-on="input:first" style="display: none;">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-responsive">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Image Viewer</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <img ng-src="data:image/jpeg;base64,{{imgDoc}}" width ="250px" height="250px"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <span class="pull-right"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button></span>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is the code in my controller that retrieves the file to display from the database and sets `{{imgDoc}}` to the selected image:

```
     $scope.getContractorDocument = function (d) {
    var id = d.FileImageReferenceID;
    contractorService.getdocument(id)
      .success(function (response) {
        var file = response[0];
        displayDocument(file);
      });
  };
    function displayDocument(file) {
    if (file.FileName == '' || file.FileName == null) {
      fileName = 'ContractorDocument';
    } else {
      fileName = file.FileName;
    }
    switch (file.vchMimeType) {

      case 'image/bmp':
      case 'image/gif':
      case 'image/jpeg':
      case 'img/jpg':
      case 'img/pjpeg':
      case 'image/png':

        $scope.imgDoc = base64ArrayBuffer(file.binFileImage);
        break;

    }


}
```

Here is what is in the base64ArrayBuffer function:

```
function base64ArrayBuffer(arrayBuffer) {
var base64 = '';
var encodings = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/';

var bytes = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
var byteLength = bytes.byteLength;
var byteRemainder = byteLength % 3;
var mainLength = byteLength - byteRemainder;

var a, b, c, d;
var chunk;

// Main loop deals with bytes in chunks of 3
for (var i = 0; i < mainLength; i = i + 3) {
  // Combine the three bytes into a single integer
  chunk = (bytes[i] << 16) | (bytes[i + 1] << 8) | bytes[i + 2];

  // Use bitmasks to extract 6-bit segments from the triplet
  a = (chunk & 16515072) >> 18; // 16515072 = (2^6 - 1) << 18
  b = (chunk & 258048) >> 12; // 258048   = (2^6 - 1) << 12
  c = (chunk & 4032) >> 6; // 4032     = (2^6 - 1) << 6
  d = chunk & 63; // 63       = 2^6 - 1

  // Convert the raw binary segments to the appropriate ASCII encoding
  base64 += encodings[a] + encodings[b] + encodings[c] + encodings[d];
}

// Deal with the remaining bytes and padding
if (byteRemainder == 1) {
  chunk = bytes[mainLength];

  a = (chunk & 252) >> 2; // 252 = (2^6 - 1) << 2

  // Set the 4 least significant bits to zero
  b = (chunk & 3) << 4; // 3   = 2^2 - 1

  base64 += encodings[a] + encodings[b] + '==';
} else if (byteRemainder == 2) {
  chunk = (bytes[mainLength] << 8) | bytes[mainLength + 1];

  a = (chunk & 64512) >> 10; // 64512 = (2^6 - 1) << 10
  b = (chunk & 1008) >> 4; // 1008  = (2^6 - 1) << 4

  // Set the 2 least significant bits to zero
  c = (chunk & 15) << 2; // 15    = 2^4 - 1

  base64 += encodings[a] + encodings[b] + encodings[c] + '=';
}

return base64;
```

}

The modal is opened using the following:

```
data-toggle="modal" data-target="#imageViewer" ng-click="getContractorDocument(d)
```

The jpeg displays quickly the first time but then display just gets slower and slower until the application locks up completely.  Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular Bootstrap Modal Slow ng-repeat in Google Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24038779/angular-bootstrap-modal-slow-ng-repeat-in-google-chrome)